# Want to use awk command within ansible playbook items

Tags: bash, awk, ansible, ansible-inventory

This is my playbook which is not working if I put the 4th item with `awk` command with double quote like below:

```yaml
tasks:
   - shell: "{{item}}"
     with_items:
      - hostname
      - df -kh
      - uptime
      - grep -i diameter /tmp/PSC-CIPDiameter_8.1_*_1.stat.0 | awk -F"," '{ if ($4!=0 || $5!=0|| $6!=0) print "Diameter  Time : "$1 "   Success: "$3 "    Fail: " $4" Timeout: " $5" Reject: " $6}' 

     register: test

   - debug:
       msg: "{{test.results|map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list}}"
```

Comment: # i also want to include below command into my item list

a=`ifconfig -a|awk -F" " '{print $1}'|grep -i en |sed 's/://g'`;for i in $a;do echo $i `ethtool $i|egrep -i "duplex|speed"`;done

Comment: Please, post some testable sample data with the expected output. Don't post them as an image or as a comment but edit them to your original question. Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: Your YAML is invalid: http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: ifconfig -a|awk -F" " '{print $1}'|grep -i en |sed 's/://g' should be $(ifconfig -a|awk -F" " '{print $1}'|grep -i en |sed 's/://g')

Comment: @Shuvhashis Paul: Welcome to SO! Make your questions [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Comment on your questions only if necessary. Update your question with the code instead and delete the comment.

Comment: @VladimirBotka mcve is now referenced as mre (for Minimal, Reproducible Example). There are [quick comment links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/279135) for those, `[mre]` in a comment will render this link and text [mre]. Same if you want to point at the fact the OP should edit something in the question, you can use `[edit]`, that renders as [edit]

Comment: @ShuvhashisPaul wrt [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051078/want-to-use-awk-command-within-ansible-playbook-items#comment115004327_65051078) - don't add additional requirements in comments where they can easily be missed, include **all** relevant information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Put the awk code into the file created from the template. This way, you can test the code separately and improve the readability of the code. For example, the template

```
shell> cat templates/script01.j2.awk 
{
  if ($4!=0 || $5!=0|| $6!=0)
    print "Diameter Time:" $1 " Success:" $3 " Fail:" $4 " Timeout:" $5 " Reject:"$6;
}
```

and the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: script01.j2.awk
        dest: script01.awk
    - shell: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - uptime
        - "echo 1,2,3,4,5,6 | awk -F',' -f script01.awk"
      register: test
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ test.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}"
```

give

```yaml
    "msg": [
        " 17:05:13 up 3 days, 13:42,  1 user,  load average: 1.93, 1.45, 1.74",
        "Diameter Time:1 Success:3 Fail:4 Timeout:5 Reject:6"
    ]
```